# Is the ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,y^3)$ Artinian? If not, what is its Krull dimension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian, artinian

So, I know that the ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,y^3)$ is Noetherian, since the ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is Noetherian. 
In order to prove that the ring is not Artinian, I've tried finding a prime ideal that isn't also a maximal ideal, but I'm stuck. I believe that the ring is Artinian after all. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ring is Artinian, indeed. The only prime ideal of $\mathbb C[x,y]$ which contains $(x^2,y^3)$ is $(x,y)$, so there is no prime non-maximal ideal in the factor ring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How would you prove that $(x,y)$ is indeed the only prime ideals which contains $(x^2,y^3)$?

Comment: If $P$ is a prime ideal and $x^2\in P$ then $x\in P$. Similarly for $y$. We get that $(x,y)\subseteq P$. But $(x,y)$ is maximal, hence $(x,y)=P$.

Answer (score 4):

Another argument why it is Artinian: Note that as a $\Bbb C$-vector space the ring is generated by $1,x,xy,xy^2,y,y^2$. This is because all higher powers of $x,y$ become zero in the quotient. So $R=\Bbb C[x,y](x^2,y^3)$ is finite dimensional as a $\Bbb C$-vector space. Every ideal of $R$ is in particular a subspace, hence any decreasing chain of ideals will stabilize because the dimension is finite, so $R$ is Artinian (this is a special case of the theorem that any f.g. module over an Artinian ring is also Artinian.)